# Retorno de sql em texto para model no entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

Tenho a classe pais e a classe estado:

```
[Table("tb_pais")]
    public class PaisModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("nome")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Column("sigla")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo sigla é obrigatório")]
        public string Sigla { get; set; }
}

[Table("tb_estado")]
    public class EstadoModel
    {

        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("nome")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Column("sigla")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo sigla é obrigatório")]
        public string Sigla { get; set; }

        [Column("id_pais")]
        [ForeignKey("Pais")]
        public int IdPais { get; set; }

        public virtual PaisModel Pais { get; set; }
}
```

Com usar o seguinte sql e retornar os dados na variavel virtual PaisModel?

```
var sql = "SELECT A.id, A.nome, A.sigla, A.id_pais as IdPais from 
 dbo.tb_estado A " +
"INNER JOIN dbo.tb_pais B ON (A.id_pais = B.id) " +
 filtroWhere +
 paginacao;

ret = db.Database.SqlQuery<EstadoModel>(sql).ToList();
```

Comment: Se você está utilizando `Entity Framework`, porque você não usa as rotinas do próprio ORM te entrega?

Comment: @TiedtTech Existe uma maneira de fazer um where ou uma paginação com if, dependendo da entrada de dados?

Comment: Está abaixo um exemplo prático. Editei as suas classes um pouco, dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo simples de utilização do `Entity Framework` (EF) e `where` dinâmico.

#### Contexto

```
public class Conexao : DbContext
{
    public Conexao()
        : base("Conexao")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Conexao>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Pais> Pais { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Estado> Estado { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {            
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

#### Models

Detalhe sobre o EF, se o nome da propriedade do `Model` for igual ao nome da coluna no banco de dados, não é necessário colocar o identificador `Column`. O mesmo vale para tabela.

**Pais**

```
[Table("tb_pais")]
public class Pais
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo sigla é obrigatório")]
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
}
```

**Estado**

```
[Table("tb_estado")]
public class Estado
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo sigla é obrigatório")]
    public string Sigla { get; set; }

    [Column("id_pais")]
    public int IdPais { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdPais")]
    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
}
```

#### System.Linq.Dynamic

Para fazer adicionar itens dinâmicos de `select, where` e afins você pode utilizar a `System.Linq.Dynamic´.

Pode instalar ela pelo `nugget`
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

#### Exemplo de utilização

Vou colocar um exemplo simples de utilização.

Nele tem o MontaWhere, que monta o `where` de forma dinâmica. O `Cidade.Descricao` faz o `where` na classe pai, pois a classe `OperacaoLocalidade` tem uma `FK` para a classe `CIDADE`.

```
using site.Dominio.Contexto;
using site.Dominio.DTO;
using site.Dominio.Entidades;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace site.Dominio.Repositorios
{
    public class OperacaoLocalidadeRepositorio
    {
        private Conexao db { get; set; }
        private UsuarioLogadoDTO usuario { get; set; }


        private string MontaWhere()
        {
            var where = String.Format("Apagado = \"N\" and VisaoID == {0}", usuario.VisaoID);
            return where;
        }

        private string MontaWhereFiltro(GridFiltroDTO parametros)
        {
            var where = "";
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parametros.filtro))
            {
                where += where.SQLWhereInteger("OperacaoLocalidadeID", parametros.filtro);
                where += where.SQLWhereMergeOr("Sigla.ToLower().Contains(@0)");
                where += where.SQLWhereMergeOr("OperacaoLocalidadeUF.Estado.Sigla.ToLower().Contains(@0)");
                where += where.SQLWhereMergeOr("OperacaoLocalidadeUF.Estado.Descricao.ToLower().Contains(@0)");
                where += where.SQLWhereMergeOr("Cidade.Descricao.ToLower().Contains(@0)");
            }
            return where;
        }

        private string MontaWherePessoa(int? pessoa)
        {
            var where = "";
            if (pessoa != null)
            {
                where = String.Format("PessoaID == {0}", pessoa);
            }
            return where;
        }

        private string MontaOrderBy(GridFiltroDTO parametros)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(parametros.orderna) ? "Sigla" : parametros.orderna + " " + parametros.ordernaTipo;
        }

        private int TotalDeRegistros(GridFiltroDTO parametros, UsuarioLogadoDTO usuarioLogado)
        {
            return
                db.OperacaoLocalidade
                .Where(MontaWhere())
                .Where(MontaWhereFiltro(parametros), parametros.filtro)
                .Where(MontaWherePessoa(usuarioLogado.PessoaID))
                .Count();
        }

        public GridResultadoDTO Grid(GridFiltroDTO parametros)
        {
            return new GridResultadoDTO(
                db.OperacaoLocalidade
                    .Where(MontaWhere())
                    .Where(MontaWhereFiltro(parametros), parametros.filtro)
                    .Where(MontaWherePessoa(usuario.PessoaID))
                    .Select(s => new {
                        s.OperacaoLocalidadeID,
                        s.Pessoa.Nome,
                        s.Sigla,
                        Estado = s.Estado.Descricao,
                        Cidade = s.Cidade.Descricao,
                        s.Status,
                        Fixo = s.Fixo == "S" ? "Sim" : "Não"
                    })
                    .OrderBy(MontaOrderBy(parametros))
                    .Skip(parametros.itensParaIgnorar)
                    .Take(parametros.itensPorPagina)                    
                    .ToArray(), TotalDeRegistros(parametros, usuario));
        }

        public SelectList ComboBox(int? pessoa) 
        { 
            return 
                new SelectList(
                    db.OperacaoLocalidade
                    .Where(MontaWhere())
                    .Where(MontaWherePessoa(pessoa))
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Sigla)
                    .Select(s => new ItemComboBoxDTO { Key = s.OperacaoLocalidadeID, Texto = s.Sigla + " [ " + s.Cidade.Descricao + " / " + s.Cidade.Estado.Sigla + " ] " }).ToArray(), 
                    "Key", "Texto"); 
        }

        public OperacaoLocalidadeRepositorio(Conexao conexao, UsuarioLogadoDTO usuarioLogado)
        {
            db = conexao;
            usuario = usuarioLogado;
        }
    }
}
```